# Expo react native material-top-tab-navigator inside scrollView not showing screen

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-tabnavigator

### When loading a tab screen using material-top-tab-navigator the screens are not displayed

---

#### version

"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.2.1"

"expo": "^45.0.0",

---

#### page where the navigator is loaded

```
return (
 <View>
      <ScrollView >
       <View>
         <TitleH2 color={colors.white} style={{marginHorizontal:20, marginBottom:20}}>Ervaringen in gebied</TitleH2>
        </View>
         <View >
            <DestinationTabs/>
         </View>
   </ScrollView>
</View> 
)
```

#### Where the navigator is created

```
  return (
        <Tab.Navigator 
          screenOptions={{
              tabBarIndicatorStyle:{ backgroundColor:colors.green_500, },
              tabBarActiveTintColor: colors.green_500,
              tabBarScrollEnabled: true,
              lazy: true,
            
          }}
          sceneContainerStyle={{
              backgroundColor: colors.green_500,
             
                }}
        > 
          <Tab.Screen name="Tab1" component={TabSceen1}  />
          <Tab.Screen name="Tab2" component={TabSceen1} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Tab3" component={TabSceen1} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Tab4" component={TabSceen2} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
  );
```

I was only able to display the screen when giving the navigator a fixed height. But then it's not scrollable and the content is not properly displayed.

Is there a way to make the screen display in a scrollview where the height is displayed based on the content size in side a screen, and where it's also able to be scrolled ?

- update question *

How do you make the tab screens appear in a scrollView

Comment: why not use flex:1 on the very first parent ?  actually i think its better to use flex:1 on every screen so it can fit the whole screen

Comment: I have tried that, but that doesn't work. The screens of the material tabs will not show up

Comment: >Is there a way to make the screen display in a scrollview where the height is displayed based on the content size in side a screen.

it already is by default, but if you want to fit the whole sceen try flexGrow:1 in scrollview it will match the parent height

Comment: Sorry, I see my question wasn't very clear. I know how to use flex and height in a scroll View. But when implementing the material tabs. The screens of it are not displaying, accept if I give it a fixed height. But then not all the content is show or their is a lot of blank space.

Comment: if flex doesn't work try using percentage for height example `"100%"`,  if its still doesn't work and need fixed height, don't use fixed but use `Dimension.get("window").height` this will get u the screen height, you can multiple by decimal or divide it its too big. but make sure import `Dimension` from react native.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions

Comment: Unfortunately, "100%" has no effect. And the fixed height makes it not scrollable. So when one of the screens has more content than that height long is, it overflows and is not scrollable

Answer (score 5):

Use this contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}} in side scroll view

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}/>
```

Comment: Depending on your implementation, doing this will render every other scrollable component, Flatlist, SectionList, unscrollable

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve that is to add fixed height to `<Tab.Navigator/>`. You can use `minHeight` for the screen to grow with content on it.

**Code:**

```
<Tab.Navigator style={{minHeight:1000}} />
```

I hope this gonna work.